# How to use two background images

Tags: jquery, html, css, image, twitter-bootstrap

I am using a Bootstrap modal in my website. I want to use two images as a background. I am able to use one image succesfully. When I try to include a second image I facing issues.

My first image appears on the whole modal and the second image is small, yet I want it to appear on top of the first image.

My CSS code for the first image is

```
.modal-content{
    background-image: url("{% static "markatix/imgs/modal/bg.png" %}");
}
```

I tried the solution in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35280560/how-to-have-two-background-images-with-css) but when written like this my first image also disappears.

I also tried

```
.modal-content{
    background-image: url("{% static "markatix/imgs/modal/bg.png" %}") ,url("{% static "markatix/imgs/modal/bg2.png" %}") ;
    background-repeat: no-repeat,no-repeat;
    background-position: center, center;
}
```

However it shows me only one image.

Comment: Can you post your HTML code please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read here: http://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_backgrounds.asp

```css
#example1 {
    background-image: url(http://www.thedesignwork.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/10/Random-Pictures-of-Conceptual-and-Creative-Ideas-02.jpg), url(https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/originals/f5/9b/1b/f59b1b0cc430702e82dea90780d7f87d.gif);
    background-position: right bottom, left top;
    background-repeat: no-repeat, no-repeat;
    background-size: 20%, 20%;
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="example1"></div>
```

Comment: Please don't use W3Schools as a resource. They are often outdated in their guides, and sometimes even completely wrong. Try using a more reliable source such as [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Background_and_Borders/Using_CSS_multiple_backgrounds)

Comment: Here is another, more reliable source: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Background_and_Borders/Using_CSS_multiple_backgrounds And here is the browser compatibility: http://caniuse.com/#feat=multibackgrounds

Answer (score 1):

You should contain another div on top of this one

you can adjust position and size of inner one by adjusting paddings of the outer one

```css
 .main-div{
      margin:0;
      padding:50px;
      width:300px;
      height:200px;
      background-image:url("https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/7/7a/Geres1.jpg/480px-Geres1.jpg");
      background-size:cover;
      background-repeat:no-repeat;
      background-position:center;
    }
    
    .overlay-div{
      margin:auto;
      padding:0;
      width:100%;
      height:100%;
      background-image:url('https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/8/85/Venus_globe.jpg/480px-Venus_globe.jpg');
      background-size:cover;
      background-repeat:no-repeat;
      background-position:center;
    }
```

```html
 <div class="main-div">
      <div class="overlay-div">
      </div>
      </div>
```

Comment: I think there is a big difference in browser-compatibility with the other multiple css background solution... I think this works 100% of the times and the other solutions fails quite often. Do you happen to know specifically what the difference is?